# How to set Apollo GraphQL end point to local IP when developing?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm developing a React frontend with a Node/Express backend using Apollo Client and  Server. The frontend was generated using `create-react-app`.

On my frontend I was adding the GraphQL endpoint using `HttpLink` from `apollo-boost` as such:

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: 'http://localhost:8080/graphql' })
```

This is fine when developing locally, however if I want to test the website (and indirectly the GraphQL end point) on a different device - all GraphQL content fails to load because the end point doesn't exist on the localhost of the device.

To combat this I added the following:

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
      ? 'http://192.168.1.25:8080/graphql'
      : 'https://example.com/graphql'
})
```

This works well, but I find myself doing development on two different machines. So the local IP which serves the GraphQL endpoint is not fixed at `192.168.1.25`.

I then searched npm and found [`internal-ip`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/internal-ip). I thought I could just import `internal-ip` and make the above into a template string as such:

```
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
      ? `http://${internalIp.v4.sync()}:8080/graphql`
      : 'https://example.com/graphql'
})
```

However, when ran through webpack `internalIp.v4.sync()` evaluates to `null`.

What's the best practise to dynamically set a local IP endpoint when working with React and webpack as outlined in the problem above? In particular, without running `npm eject`?

Comment: Interesting the syntax highlighting seems to have a problem with `//` in template strings.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a node library, so it won't work inside your frontend code. If you're using webpack, you can use [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to evaluate some expression and then set it to a global variable that'll be available anywhere in your frontend code.

You could also use a tool like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) to expose a public URL for your local development environment.

```
// webpack.config.js
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  SERVER_URL: JSON.stringify(`${internalIp.v4.sync()}/graphql`),
})

// elsewhere
const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: SERVER_URL })
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a `create-react-app` friendly way of doing this? That is, without running `npm run eject`.

Answer (score 0):

I will definitely suggest the use of .ngrok as already suggested by @Daniel

1.Use .ngrok to expose your local server end point. You will get a public server url which you can consume from anywhere on the internet

2.You can create **.env.development.local** file with an env variable.

For more info regarding env files in **Create React App** priority see this [link](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables#what-other-env-files-can-be-used)

e.g

REACT_APP_SERVER_URL= http://192.168.1.25:8080/graphql

// Or the url given by ngrok

3.Use SERVER_URL from .env file without ejecting

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: REACT_APP_SERVER_URL})

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that I couldn't use ngrok for this purpose without paying as I would require a fixed custom subdomain from them to point the GraphQL endpoint to?

Comment: Or rather, if I wanted to use the free plan, I would have to rebuild the bundle with the random subdomain each time I start the dev. server?

Comment: @BML91 for free plan you need to rebuild the bundle at least after 6 or 7 hours till the time your domain is valid